# Variable indefinida al enviar datos desde controlador a la vista

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto de práctica donde saco una información de la base de datos y la muestro en una vista como tipo "perfil".

Al momento de mostrarla, me sale error de variable indefinida, pero esa variable ya se trae en la consulta

Este es el método del modelo usuario que trae la información de la base de datos:

```
function datosUsuario($id){
        $this->db->select('nombre, apellido, direccion, telefono, correo');
        $this->db->where('id_usuario', $id);
        //$this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_usuarios');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Este es el de la vista:

```
<h1>Bienvenido&nbsp;<span id="usuario">@<?= $id; ?></span></h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-1">
      <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <p><?= $nombre; ?></p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

y por último, este fragmento, que es la función del controlador:

```
function index(){

    if($this->session->userdata('login_ok'))
    {
        $data = $this->usuario->datosUsuario((string)$this->session->userdata('id_usuario'));
        $data['id'] = $this->session->userdata('id_usuario');
        $this->load->view("perfil", $data);
    }else{
        Redirect('inicio/index', 'location');
    }
}
```

Comment: Por lo que veo en el codigo en ningun momento le asignar a $nombre un valor, deberias probar a sacarlo del $query , asignarselo y luego mostrarlo, posiblemente igual con el $id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analizando tu pregunta, falta un poco de manejo en como enviar la información desde el controlador a la vista.

El modelo seria recomendable revolver un objeto, es mas fácil de manejar en la vista. [Dejo el link con mas información](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=result_array#id1).

```
function datosUsuario($id){
    $this->db->select('nombre, apellido, direccion, telefono, correo');
    $this->db->where('id_usuario', $id);
    //$this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_usuarios');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Luego viene el controlador, en donde en tu código no se aprecia si en el constructor del controlador cargas el modelo donde se encuentra la función y en como intentas pasar los datos que retorna el modelo al controlador.

```
function __construct()
{
        parent::__construct();
        //Suponiendo que se llame asi tu modelo
        $this->load->model('usuario');
}

function index()
{
  if($this->session->userdata('login_ok'))
  {
     //Primero guardar la id_usuario en una variable
     $id_usuario = $this->session->userdata('id_usuario');
     //Aqui esta el primer detalle, tienes que asignar un Indice para después recuperar la información en la vista
     $data['info_usuarios'] = $this->usuario->datosUsuario($id_usuario);
     $data['id'] = $id_usuario;
     $this->load->view("perfil", $data);
  }
  else
  {
     Redirect('inicio/index', 'location');
  }
}
```

Para finalizar con la vista, en donde seria algo asi

```html
 <h1>Bienvenido&nbsp;<span id="usuario">@<?= $id ?></span></h1>
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-1">
              <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
              <p><?= $info_usuarios->nombre ?></p>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Si analizas la vista, el id se usa de esa forma ya que es solo un dato que pasas, en cambio el otro es un [Objeto](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.object.php), y debes recorrerlo de esa forma. Espero sea de ayuda mi respuesta :)

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ha servido de guia para resolver el problema :)